# android not able to commit on git

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I am using android studio 1.5.1. I am using bitbucket for version control. All my files except for ExampleUnitTest.java are getting committed and added to the repository. Can anyone tell me why only this file is not able to commit. Thank you.

Comment: What does `git status` show you?  If I had to guess right now, I would say that you never added this file to the index by using `git add path/to/file/`

Comment: it shows nothing. when i click on the blue commit button for this file nothing happens. Also when i commit this file with other files it only shows a progress bar and no file is committed. So to  commit i always have to deselect this file and the commit. Then all the files are commited

Comment: Can you show me what `git status` shows you?  I'm not familiar with the Android Studio Git plugin.

Comment: sorry i am not getting what status you want to see. i have never used git apart from android studio

Comment: Open up the Git Bash, which is a console program, navigate to the directory where your project is, and type `git status`.

Comment: OK i will do and tell

Comment: sorry i was not able to understand git bash. i was unable to go navigate to my project folder. But from this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/checking-git-project-status.html?origin=old_help i got the status. The status is " File is scheduled for addition to the repository. " from this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html . The color is green. Sorry took a lot of time answer back

Comment: I can't advise you on the plugin.  If you tell what the `git bash` says then many people will have something to say.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am not good at command lines. Hence i am relying on the plugin as it is simple to use. But anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> But from this link [Checking Git Project Status](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/checking-git-project-status.html?origin=old_help) I got the status.
>   The status is

```
File is scheduled for addition to the repository.
```

> From this link [File Status Highlights](https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html), the color is green.

So all you need to do a is "[Checking In Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/checking-in-files.html?origin=old_help)": a new commit will be created with that `ExampleUnitTest.java` in it, since it is marked as "scheduled for addition".